# unable to save values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to save data in two different database tables , when i run two query it save 0 in the integer field.

```
     $sql = 'insert into photo_album( user_id, photo_id, album_id )
            values(". $user_id.",".$photo_id.",". $album_id.")';

          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

but when i run query as hard coded values it work fine.

```
      INSERT INTO
       photo_album( photo_id, user_id, album_id )
        VALUES(8299,214,316)
```

can some one tell what is wrong ?

Comment: You started your string with single quotes `'` and you want to concat it with double quotes `"`? :D don't think that's going to work

Comment: What's the result of `echo $sql;` ?

Comment: I also try this but same result

Comment: echo result is the INSERT INTO
       photo_album( photo_id, user_id, album_id )
        VALUES(8299,214,316)

Comment: try your query in phpmyadmin

Comment: First go through : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php then change your query to `INSERT INTO photo_album( photo_id, user_id, album_id )VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

Comment: @SohailYasmin try using `intval(<var_name>)`

Comment: @SohailYasmin: Is this the second Query(to second database)?. And what about first?

Comment: @MMK database is only one table are two in the second table , i am facing issue , while inserting data same time in both table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finely i manage to solve this issue , It is very strange you people will laugh at me  / not believe me , I rename the field to some other name it start saving the value again , then i again rename to original name , I saw every this is working perfectly.

Thank you for your help.

please tell me if this is bug in mysql or not

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array(
   'user_id' => '$user_id' ,
   'photo_id' => '$photo_id' ,
   'album_id' => '$album_id'
);

$this->db->insert('photo_album', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(Don't mix single and double quotes! They are different :D)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `photo_album`(photo_id, user_id, album_id)
        VALUES('" . $photo_id . "', '" . $user_id . "', '" . $album_id . "')";
```

EDIT after comment:

Then try it to put `'` around the values. Maybe the are stored as strings.

Also don't change the order of the column's to insert :D

Comment: also try the same but failed to save value

Comment: @SohailYasmin Updated my answer! Maybe you store the id's as strings so put `'` around them

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Ah you got me again xD (Think OP's problem is the order of the column's and the difference between single and double quotes)

Comment: @SohailYasmin Think you have a wrong order of the columns!

Comment: columns are not the issue at least it has to save some thing in the table

Answer (score 0):

try like this in codeigniter format

```
$data = array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'photo_id' => $photo_id,
                'album_id' => $album_id
             );
            $this->db->insert('photo_album', $data);
```

Comment: after this can you do this echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: INSERT INTO `photo_album` (`user_id`, `photo_id`, `album_id`) VALUES (214, 8323, 316)

Comment: its means query is right..then there is no chance insert 0 values

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO photo_album (user_id,photo_id,album_id)
                VALUES('$this->user_id','$this->photo_id','$this->album_id')";
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using  `codeigniter` then try like this:

```
$dataArr = array(
    'photo_id' => $photo_id,
   'user_id' => $user_id,
   'album_id' => $album_id
);

$this->db->insert('photo_album', $dataArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Separate variables

```
$sql = 'insert into photo_album( `user_id`, `photo_id`, `album_id` )
        values("' .$user_id. '","' .$photo_id. '","' .$album_id. '")';
```